# Question was set on "hold", but nobody tells my which StackExchange site matches for this question

Tags: support, scope, on-hold

My question was set on hold because it is off-topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801013/which-vm-needs-more-resources

Unfortunately nobody told me which StackExchange site matches for this question.

How to proceed?

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_ There may not be a SE site match. SuperUser may be a option.

Comment: @Cerbrus following your argumentation the site software-recommendations may not exist. What am I missing? BTW several thousand question on StackoverFlow get answered by "use tool xyz".

Comment: Several thousand? Nope. They usually get closed as being a "tool request". http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is not SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus and even then Software Recs has its own standards, is not your run off the mill software recommendation request you see everyday on SO, we close them fast too!

Comment: Also note that it is _not_ anybody's obligation to provide you with an alternative site to post on. Choosing the right site is up to _you_.

Comment: Each [se] has a help/on-topic page where we can learn what kind of questions one can ask there.

Answer (score 2):

- If these VMs are your home-toys - SuperUser
- If it's your professional activity - ServerFault

but in any case **not in form** "I need a tool...", but "how to detect, adding to which VM some resources will be more profitable" and answers on *such* questions will have value not only for you (we, answers, aren't free helpdesk here), but for future readers also.

Nobody care about *your personal troubles* in the (real) world

Comment: "Nobody care about your personal troubles in the (real) world". That is really the way you see the world? I have wife, children, parents and friends which care about my personal troubles.

Comment: @AndrewT. I see this problem coming up again and again: "which stackexchange site to use". If people do the wrong decision, they get down-votes and angry replies. I think the current situation is the problem, not the people choosing the wrong site. People are not perfect. A tool or better docs could help.